# VBA - Combining worksheet changes

Tags: vba, excel

I`m an absolute VBA noob but given the shifting demands of my job, lately I had to verge into coding territory because we are trying to automate quite a lot of tasks. What I already have is this code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim strField As String

strField = "Manager"

On Error Resume Next
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


If Target.Address = Range("D1").Address Then

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            With pt.PageFields(strField)
                For Each pi In .PivotItems
                    If pi.Value = Target.Value Then
                        .CurrentPage = Target.Value
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        .CurrentPage = "(All)"
                    End If
                Next pi
            End With
        Next pt
    Next ws

End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I am trying to combine this with the following code:

```
Range("AC22:AC60").Copy Range("AF22:AF60")
Range("AL22:Al60").Copy Range("AN22:AN60")
Range("AU22:AU60").Copy Range("AW22:AW60")
```

but I only want the ranges to copy if the D1 range in the first code changes. Obviously I want to automate and not to code the copies to a macro, so I please help me how to kill two birds with the one stone here.

How do I combine this ?

Much appreciated,

Comment: I might misunderstand your question, but why don't you just put the copy code into the If statement?

Comment: Well, the primary goal of the code is to synchronize the pivot tables based on D1`s value, secondarily I would also like this copy paste to happen, but in such a way that does not interfere with the pivot operation..

When I try to put this together, the code doesnt execute because there are multiple ranges in there ( I suspect ).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should simply do the trick (but I'm really not sure if I fully understand your question):

```
If Target.Address = Range("D1").Address Then

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
        With pt.PageFields(strField)
            For Each pi In .PivotItems
                If pi.Value = Target.Value Then
                    .CurrentPage = Target.Value
                    Exit For
                Else
                    .CurrentPage = "(All)"
                End If
            Next pi
        End With
    Next pt
Next ws

Range("AC22:AC60").Copy Range("AF22:AF60")
Range("AL22:Al60").Copy Range("AN22:AN60")
Range("AU22:AU60").Copy Range("AW22:AW60")

End If
```

If this is not what you need, do you mean this?

```
If Target.Address = Range("D1").Address Then

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
        With pt.PageFields(strField)
            For Each pi In .PivotItems
                If pi.Value = Target.Value Then
                    .CurrentPage = Target.Value
                    Range("AC22:AC60").Copy Range("AF22:AF60")
                    Range("AL22:Al60").Copy Range("AN22:AN60")
                    Range("AU22:AU60").Copy Range("AW22:AW60")
                    Exit For
                Else
                    .CurrentPage = "(All)"
                End If
            Next pi
        End With
    Next pt
Next ws

End If
```